# How to send mail from yahoo mail Id in VB.NET or C#.NET code

Tags: c#, vb.net

I want to send mail from my yahoomail Id.How to send mail from yahoo mail Id in VB.NET or C#.NET code. Kind help needed.. Advance Thanks.

Sivakumar.P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some examples of doing a basic html email messages.

http://help.yahoo.com/l/us/yahoo/mail/original/mailplus/pop/pop-14.html

```
  ' VB

    Dim m As MailMessage = New MailMessage
    m.From = New MailAddress("you@yahoo.com", "Your Name")
    m.To.Add(New MailAddress("Recipient@somedomain.com", "Recipient Name"))
    m.Subject = "Hello"
    ' Specify an HTML message body
    m.Body = "<html><body><h1>My Message</h1><br>Put the body here.</body></html>"
    m.IsBodyHtml = True
    ' Send the message
    Dim client As SmtpClient = New SmtpClient("smtp.mail.yahoo.com")
    client.Send(m)






  // C#

    MailMessage m = new MailMessage();
    m.From = new MailAddress("you@yahoo.com", "Your Name");
    m.To.Add(new MailAddress("Recipient@somedomain.com", "Recipient Name"));
    m.Subject = "Hello";
    // Specify an HTML message body
    m.Body = "<html><body><h1>My Message</h1><br>Put the body here.</body></html>";
    m.IsBodyHtml = true;
    // Send the message
    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.mail.yahoo.com");
    client.Send(m);
```

Answer (score 0):

The general idea can be found [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/sendemail)

For specifics of Yahoo SMTP, log in to your Yahoo account and click on "Account Info", then "POP, SMTP and NNTP server settings"